# How to mock Spring dependencies in mockito

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to mock Spring Beans. I am able to Mock object B and C. But am not able to Mock the object inside class B. 
The mock that is inserted in class A contains B . but X and Y are null even though i have mocked them. is there any way in Mockito to mock the Objects of member of member inside the Spring bean.

```
@Named
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class A {        
    @Inject
    private B b;
    @Inject
    private C c;        
}

@Named
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class B {        
    @Inject
    private X x;
    @Inject
    private Y y;        
}
```

The Testing Class in which i need to populate all the dependencies of Class A.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {     

    @InjectMocks
    A a = new A();    

    @Mock
    private B b;
    @Mock
    private C c;

    @Mock
    private X x;
    @Mock
    private Y y;
}
```

Comment: You are creating an instance with A a = new A(); You should be injecting it?

Comment: Problem remains same even if i do  @InjectMocks
    A a;

Comment: A doesn't depend on X nor Y. There is no point in mocking them. B and C are mocks, so they don't depend on X and Y either. X and Y are completely irrelevant for the test of A.

Comment: my question was .. is there way to mock the X, Y as they are inside B . cause when i do @injectMocks for B then B comes as null in A.
and values of X,Y are populated in B.

Comment: Why do you want to mock X and Y. Why do you need that to test A, which only depends on B and C?

Comment: methods used in A uses instance of B. which in turn uses instances of  X, Y. it is giving nullpointerException. for X, Y.

Comment: That's why you should mock B. A mock B doesn't use X nor Y. It's a mock, i.e. a completely fake object that doesn't do anything except what you're telling it to do. In the posted code, B is mocked. You can just remove the x and y variables which are useless.

Comment: @dnegi as JB Nizet said, you are mocking methods of `B`, so you are not calling those in `B` that needs `X` and `Y`, so your `foo()` in mocked B simply returns some result... That's it... Can you be more specific if something is not  clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do next. In this case, B will be spy object so you can mock methods results on it if needed. Or you can use real B methods with mocked X and Y methods.

```
    @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {        

    @Mock
    private X x;
    @Mock
    private Y y;


        @Spy
        @InjectMocks
        private B b;

        @Mock
        private C c;

        @InjectMocks
        A a; 

        @Before
        public void setUp() {
           MockitoAnnotations.initMock(this);
        }

    }
```

Comment: this was precisely what i was looking for. Now am able to set X,Y inside of B which in turn is member of A.

Answer (score 2):

If you want test your class `A`, you don't need to mock class `X` and `Y`. You should mock only class `B` and `C` and of course you have to specify what your mock objects return when they were invoked.

Here is simple example of your class with one method.

```
@Named
@Scope(value = "prototype")
public class A {
    @Inject
    private B b;
    @Inject
    private C c;

    public int someMethod(){
        int value = b.otherMethod();

        return Math.abs(value);
    }
}

@Named
@Scope(value = "prototype")
 class B {
    @Inject
    private X x;
    @Inject
    private Y y;

    public int otherMethod(){
        int value = x.something();
        int otherValuey = y.something();

        return value + otherValuey;
    }
}
```

And your test might look like this.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {
    @InjectMocks
    private A a;

    //mock only B and C
    @Mock
    private B b;
    @Mock
    private C c;

    public void shouldTestSomething(){
        //given
        Mockito.when(b.otherMethod()).thenReturn(-1); //you specified what happen when method will invoked

        //when
        int value = a.someMethod();

        //then
        Assert.assertEquals(1, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Springs test runner](http://patrickgrimard.com/2011/02/17/running-unit-tests-with-the-spring-framework/) with a test application context xml.

In this test application context you can create any mock simply with using springs factory method attribute on the Mockito class:

```
<bean id="mockBean" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock"> 
    <constructor-arg value="com.package.ClassToBeMocked" /> 
</bean>
```

Then you can inject this mockBean into your other bean.