# How to mock Spring dependencies with JUnit 5?

Tags: java, junit, mockito, wicket, junit5

We have to test class, see below. Our question is how can we fill the dependencies, so that we can test the original class you see below.

```
public class FragenAntwortenDataprovider extends SortableDataProvider<FragenAntworten, String> {

    @SpringBean
    private IFragenAntwortenService service;

    private IModel<FragenAntworten> filter;


    public FragenAntwortenDataprovider(IModel<FragenAntworten> filter){
        this.filter = filter;
        Injector.get().inject(this);
        setSort("id", SortOrder.DESCENDING);  // absteigend sortieren
    }


    @Override
    public Iterator<? extends FragenAntworten> iterator(long first, long count){
        List<FragenAntworten> list = load();
        List<FragenAntworten> sublist = list.subList((int) first, (int) (first+count));
        return sublist.iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public long size() {return getListSize();}

    @Override
    public IModel<FragenAntworten> model(FragenAntworten object) {
        return Model.of(object);
    }

    private void sort(final List<FragenAntworten> list){

    }

    private long getListSize(){
        List<FragenAntworten> list = service.ladeAlle(filter.getObject().getSystem());
        return list.size();
    }


    private List<FragenAntworten> load(){
        List<FragenAntworten> list = service.ladeAlle(filter.getObject().getSystem());
        return list;
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to use Mockito

Comment: Thank you but, how can we use it? So which code do we need, to make the test?

Comment: Can you show your existing test class code please?

Comment: package de.econsuite.wartung.webapp.components.benutzer;

import org.junit.Test;

import de.econsuite.wartung.webapp.WebTestBase;
import de.econsuite.wartung.webapp.model.Benutzer;
import de.econsuite.wartung.webapp.pages.benutzer.BenutzerPage;


public class FragenAntwortenDataproviderTest extends WebTestBase {

    @Test
    public void Testing() {
        BenutzerPage page = new BenutzerPage();
        tester.startPage(page);
        tester.assertRenderedPage(BenutzerPage.class);
    }
}

Comment: @mrkernelpanic thank you, above is our code.

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code into it.

Comment: Paste the Junit test class you have created so far using Mockito, and then point out where you are stuck.

Comment: Also please first read existing answers such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34497046, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457239, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10906945, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55134162. It seems your problem is not special compared to those other questions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use Spring you can use its `ReflectionUtils` helper class to inject the dependency:

```
IFragenAntwortenService service = mock(IFragenAntwortenService.class);
IModel<FragenAntworten> model = ...;
FragenAntwortenDataprovider provider = new FragenAntwortenDataprovider(model);
Field serviceField = ReflectionUtils.findField("service", provider);
ReflectionUtils.setField(serviceField, provider, service);
```

Another option is to introduce package-private setter for `service` field and avoid using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

You should have your original class have the dependencies injected with `@Autowired` or `@Inject`. Actually you should not use field injection, but constructor injection. Then you should use the `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` for the JUnit 5 test class. Every dependency you have to define as a `@Mock` and for the class you wish to test you use the `@InjectMocks` annotation.

This is the constructor injection to use:

```
public class FragenAntwortenDataprovider extends SortableDataProvider<FragenAntworten, String> {

    private IFragenAntwortenService service;

    private IModel<FragenAntworten> filter;

    @Inject
    public FragenAntwortenDataprovider(IFragenAntwortenService service, IModel<FragenAntworten> filter){
        this.service = service;
        this.filter = filter;
        //I guess you don't need the injector anymore
        //Injector.get().inject(this);
        setSort("id", SortOrder.DESCENDING);  // absteigend sortieren
    }
    //Rest of class
}
```

And this is then a test-class:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class testClass() {
    @Mock
    private IFragenAntwortenService service;

    @Mock
    private IModel<FragenAntworten> filter;

    @InjectMocks
    FragenAntwortenDataprovider sut; //System under Test

    @Test
    void test() {
        //Testcode
        // Control the mock with 
        when(service.anymethod()).thenReturn(result);

        var result = sut.callMethodToTest();

        // verify all calls
        verify(service, times(1)).anymethod();

        // and assert
        assertNotNull(result);
    }
}
```